# Is it possible to add more than one Wizard to a WizardDialog to create a chain of wizards?

Tags: eclipse, jface, wizard

I have created a wizard which contains a `WizardSelectionPage`. I can select a node and thereby load a nested wizard. So far so good.

I would like to be able to chain a number of wizards within one supervising wizard. Depending on the wizard type selected, this might be just one wizard or a small number (max.4). Only when all wizards have gathered their data will the supervisor persist their results.

Just to explain. I have a number of actions governed by wizards. I want to be able to activate then separately or in groups.

So, how might I best combine the individual wizards into a composite wizard?

Comment: You can reuse wizard pages in several wizards if you want.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for your comment. I realise this but I'm assuming that each action will need 1 or more pages. I think that I'll need a wizard to supervise the pages as required by each action